# Organization security policy error in terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp

I am getting the error below  during terraform apply in cloud build pipeline and cloud build has these roles : Compute Organization Firewall Policy Admin
, Owner, and compute admin :
for Creating OrganizationSecurityPolicy: error while retrieving operation: googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.globalOperations.get' permission for 'locations/global/operations/org-66596309756-1634926613476-5cef50407b412-cf45ce60-0943c3bd', forbidden

Answer (score 0):

Typically 403 error is gcp permissions error, check IAM and give cloud build account roles.

Also tell you that it is a bad practice for the cloud build role to have owner permissions. I would recommend that you make another service account and give it specific roles for what you want to do.